# Finding Base Overlap Counts and Internal Gap in Two Strings

Tags: string, perl, bioinformatics

I have this two strings of equal length, which I need to compare.
I want to find overlap base(.) and internal gap (*). Below is the example:

```
------ACTAAAAATACAAAAA--TTAGCCAGGCGTGGTGGCAC
-----TACTAAAAATACAAAAAAATTAGCCAGGTGTGGTGG---
      ................**.................
```

Number of overlap = 33.
Number of internal gap = 2.

I have no problem finding the number of overlap. But I have problem
finding internal gap. Below is the current code I have. It is horribly slow.
In principle I need to compute millions of such pairs.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my $s1 = "------ACTAAAAATACAAAAA--TTAGCCAGGCGTGGTGGCAC";
my $s2 = "-----TACTAAAAATACAAAAAAATTAGCCAGGTGTGGTGG---";

print "$s1\n";
print "$s2\n";


my %base = ("A" => 1, "T" => 1, "C" => 1, "G" => 1);

my $ovlp_basecount = 0;
my $internal_gap = 0;

foreach my $si ( 0 .. length($s1)  ) {


    my $base1 = substr($s1,$si,1);
    my $base2 = substr($s2,$si,1);


    # Overlap
    if ( $base{$base1} && $base{$base2} ) {
        $ovlp_basecount++;
    }

    # Not sure how to compute internal gap

}


print "TOTAL OVERLAP BASE = $ovlp_basecount\n";
print "TOTAL Internal Gap \?\n";
```

Please advice how can I find internal gap and overlap efficiently.

Comment: The 34th character in each of your strings is different (C & T).  Is that deliberate?

Comment: @Mike: Yes, deliberate. It's called mismatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a bitwise OR on the strings to find the the areas in one string that overlap blank areas in the other.  This process also has the effect of revealing the overlap by converting non-overlapping characters to lower case, thus making finding the overlap quite simple too:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $s1 = "------ACTAAAAATACAAAAA--TTAGCCAGGCGTGGTGGCAC";
my $s2 = "-----TACTAAAAATACAAAAAAATTAGCCAGGTGTGGTGG---";

$s1 =~ tr/-/\x20/;
$s2 =~ tr/-/\x20/;
my $or = $s1 | $s2;
(my $gap) = $or =~ m/^.*[ACTG]([actg]+)[ACTG].*$/;
(my $overlap = $or) =~ s/[^A-Z]//g;

print "s1:      '$s1'\n";
print "s2:      '$s2'\n";
print "OR:      '$or'\n";
printf "Gap:     '%s' (%d)\n", $gap,     length $gap;
printf "Overlap  '%s' (%d)\n", $overlap, length $overlap;
```

Prints:

```
s1:      '      ACTAAAAATACAAAAA  TTAGCCAGGCGTGGTGGCAC'
s2:      '     TACTAAAAATACAAAAAAATTAGCCAGGTGTGGTGG   '
OR:      '     tACTAAAAATACAAAAAaaTTAGCCAGGWGTGGTGGcac'
Gap:     'aa' (2)
Overlap  'ACTAAAAATACAAAAATTAGCCAGGWGTGGTGG' (33)
```

For more information on string bitwise operations:

http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8214/08w/notes/bit_operations.txt

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the gaps never overlap, you can solve this using regular expressions. Here's an answer for your `s1`.

```
echo '------ACTAAAAATACAAAAA--TTAGCCAGGCGTGGTGGCAC' | perl -ne '$s = 0; foreach(/[GTAC](-+)[GTAC]/) { $s += length($1); } print "$s\n";'
2
```

Comment: unless there are quite severe constraints on what the input data may be, I would consider it unlikely that one can make the assumption that the gaps won't overlap (from a biological POV)

Comment: @PhiS If this were an ordinary sequence alignment, there shouldn't be any overlapping gaps unless this is the result of a multiple sequence alignment.